# How to read an image without saving it in the current working directory in python

Tags: python, base64, numpy-ndarray, opencv

I have a list of images in the form of base64 strings and i have converted each string to numpy n dimensional array now i want to compare these images one by one with image i have in my directory.
If i have to save all the images that are in the list as base64 strings it will be very slow process.
Is there any way to read the images without saving it to the directory?

```
import base64

import cv2
import numpy as np


def compare(staticImage, ImageFromList):
    original = cv2.imread(staticImage)
    for i in ImageFromList:
        nparr = np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(i), np.uint8)
        image = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        cv2.imwrite("imgg.jpg", image)
        image_to_compare = cv2.imread("imgg.jpg")
        # 1) Check for similarities between the 2 images
        # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
        sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
        kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
        kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)

        index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
        search_params = dict()
        flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

        matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)

        good_points = []
        for m, n in matches:
            if m.distance < 0.6 * n.distance:
                good_points.append(m)

        if len(good_points) > 0:
            return 1
        else:
            continue
```

**I don't want to save the image for every iteration**

> Is there any alternative to this process